# TeamCity returns No such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError) but terminal runs fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, teamcity

I've just setup 3 osx agents to run the CI for our ruby project. 2 of these agents are running our specs perfectly, starting their agents correctly etc. The third machine constantly returns No such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError). I have navigated to the work folder (the check out folder for the project) and i can run the commands i need the CI to run (specifically a rake task rake spec) and they run fine. It would seem my agent is picking up an incorrect version of ruby or rubygems somehow

which ruby returns (on all machines)
/opt/local/bin/ruby
which gems returns (on all machines)
/opt/local/bin/gem

i'm not sure what to try next?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking whether /opt/local/bin/ is in the PATH environment variable when your agents run.
To do this you could make a simple agent that just writes `ENV['PATH']` out to a file, without pulling any libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If these are launchd agents, keep in mind that launchd does not feed your scripts the same environment variables you're going to get by logging into a shell in Terminal.